# How to associate the search button for the input field for which its called in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a form which has few input fields that are generated with for loop and each input has a search button.
On click of my search button calls the method on all the input fields. How to associate the search for the particular input field for which its called.

```
<nz-form-item
      *ngFor="let ctrl of formService.getFormStructure(); let i = index"
    >
      <nz-form-label class="form-label" nzSpan="10" nzFor="{{ ctrl.name }}">{{
        ctrl.label
      }}</nz-form-label>
      <nz-form-control nzSpan="14">
        <span *ngIf="ctrl.type === 'date'">
          <nz-range-picker
            [nzRanges]="ranges"
            nzFormat="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
          ></nz-range-picker>
        </span>
        <div *ngIf="ctrl.type === 'text'">
          <div class="inputSearch">
            <input
              nz-input
              [type]="ctrl.type"
              [formControlName]="ctrl.name"
              id="{{ ctrl.name }}"
            />
            <span
              *ngIf="ctrl.search"
              nz-icon
              [nzType]="'search'"
              ngClass="search"
              (click)="fieldSearch($event)"
            ></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="ctrl.search && searchClicked" class="transfer">
          <app-report-search></app-report-search>
        </div>
        <span *ngIf="ctrl.type === 'select'">
          <nz-select
            nzShowSearch
            nzAllowClear
            nzPlaceHolder="Select {{ ctrl.label }}"
          >
            <!-- <nz-option *ngFor="let option of ctrl.options" nzLabel="{{option}}" nzValue="{{option}}"></nz-option> -->
          </nz-select>
        </span>
      </nz-form-control>
    </nz-form-item>
```

The fieldSearch method is getting called for all the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

When we have a function in an event in .html, we can pass all the arguments we need (furthermore the `$event`), e.g.

```
(click)="fieldSearch($event,ctrl,i)"
```

And your function

```
fieldSearch(event:any,ctrl:any,i:number)
{
   ...
}
```

NOTE: **NOT** use a function in the ngFor (really we should avoid use functions in .html to show a list or a result)

```
controls:any[]=[]; //<--use a variable

//in some place, e.g. in ngOnInit
ngOnInit(){
  this.controls=formService.getFormStructure();
}
```

And

```
<nz-form-item *ngFor="let ctrl of controls; let i = index">
   ...
</nz-form-item>
```

Comment: I want to add a antd transfer component for each input when that particular input's search is called. How can i do that.